# extract data from a textarea of list and put it into another textarea

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

When I want to extract data from a textarea of list and put it into another textarea , I have the problem of div. it look like this when my information appears

[image]

I want to remove the start (div) and the last (div) and conserve my text !
I am working in sharepoint online using JavaScript.
thanks for help !

Comment: Please share the code used so far

Comment: Yes, we don't know how you do the copy from one textarea to the other. Is this also done in javascript or are you using something else?

Comment: i'm using just javascript and the textarea in two diifferent lists

Comment: Please share the code. I will give  you a 2 line solution

Answer (score 0):

To strip the Html, you could do something like this:

```
function stripHtml(body) {
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var result = body.replace(regex, "");
    return result;
}
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use text() function ex.

```
var divText = $("#myDiv").text();
```